# Scrapy CSV export reside in 1 cell

Tags: python-2.7, csv, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to write to a csv with each data observation stored in one line. However, I have all observations reside in one cell. I tried with `yield item` to replace `item.append(item)` and `return items`, but it didn't work either.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from gdp.items import gdpItem
import unicodecsv as csv

class gdp_spider2(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'gdp_spider2'
allowed_domains = ['statdb.dgbas.gov.tw/']
start_urls = ['http://statdb.dgbas.gov.tw/pxweb/Dialog/varval.asp?ma=NA8101A1Q&ti=Principal%20Figures%282008SNA%29-Quarterly&path=../PXfileE/NationalIncome/&lang=1&strList=L']

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def parse(self, response):
    items = []

    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(response.url)
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Select all').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[contains(text(),"GDP (Million N.T.$,at Current Prices)")]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[contains(text(),"Data")]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="SUBMIT"]').click()

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=self.driver.page_source)
    data = hxs.xpath("//table[@class='pxtable']//tbody//tr")

    for datum in data:
        item = gdpItem()
        item ["date"] = datum.xpath('//td[1]/text()').extract()
        item ["data"] = datum.xpath('//td[2]/text()').extract()

        items.append(item)
        return items
```

[CSV image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxoW9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    items = []
    item = gdpItem()
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(response.url)
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Select all').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[contains(text(),"GDP (Million N.T.$,at Current Prices)")]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[contains(text(),"Data")]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="SUBMIT"]').click()

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=self.driver.page_source)
    data = hxs.xpath("//table[@class='pxtable']//tbody//tr")

    for datum in data:
        item ["date"] = datum.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract()
        item ["data"] = datum.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()

        yield item
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! May I ask you why the 'item=gdpItem()' should be moved up?

Comment: Items work as a pipeline. You don't need to call the gdpItem () again and again.